# Pagoda Box site shows white screen on Android Galaxy S3 browser

Tags: android, cakephp

Major head scratcher happening today. I developed a Cake app, hosted on Pagoda Box, that runs fine on all browsers except Android native browser on the Galaxy S3. It displays a white screen:
http://broomage.pagodabox.com/sweepstakes/MetsMoments2013

However, I uploaded this app to a standard LAMP server so I could debug it more quickly, and it showed up just fine! See here:
http://epi.qa/broomage/sweepstakes/MetsMoments2013

I'm really mystified at this point, since it now seems specific to Pagoda Box. I've checked the apache/php/cake logs and nothing weird is showing up. I can also "view source" and see that everything seems to be loading properly--only the browser just shows a white screen. This problem also happens on certain sites that use the Bootstrap library, but will sometimes show up if you go to another URL then hit the back button. But this particular site just shows a white screen on the S3 no matter what I do. Any ideas???

Answer (score 1):

Grrr, I think I narrowed it down to a gzip issue: If you are serving certain assets thru a php script, the size may be reported as a mismatch w/ the compressed size, which screws up rendering on lackluster browsers like that of android.